# How to find and append dictionary values which are present in a list

Tags: python

I have a list which has unique sorted values

```
arr = ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Chris', 'Dean', 'Flower']
```

I have a dictionary which has values as such

```
dict = {
  'abc': {'Dean': 1, 'Adam':0, 'Chris':1},
  'def': {'Flower':0, 'Ben':1, 'Dean':0}
}
```

From looking at values from arr I need to have each item and if the value isn't present in subsequent smaller dict that should be assigned a value -1

Result

```
dict = {
  'abc': {'Adam':0, 'Ben':-1, 'Chris':1, 'Dean': 1, 'Flower':-1},
  'def': {'Adam':-1, 'Ben':1, 'Chris':-1, 'Dean': 0, 'Flower':0}
}
```

how can I achieve this using list and dict comprehensions in python

Comment: don't use `dict` as your variable because `dict` is a Python built-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dd = {
    key: {k: value.get(k, -1) for k in arr}
    for key, value in dd.items()
}
```

`{k: value.get(k, -1) for k in arr}` will make sure that your keys are in the same order as you defined in the `arr` list.

---

A side note on the order of keys in [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

> Dictionaries preserve insertion order. Note that updating a key does
> not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the
> end.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion
> order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not make a variable called `dict`, rename it to `dct` or something since `dict` it is a reserved python internal.
As for your question: just iterate through your `dct` and add the missing keys using `setdefault`:

```
arr = ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Chris', 'Dean', 'Flower']


dct = {
  'abc': {'Dean': 1, 'Adam':0, 'Chris':1},
  'def': {'Flower':0, 'Ben':1, 'Dean':0}
}

def add_dict_keys(dct, arr):
    for key in arr:
        dct.setdefault(key, -1)
    return dct

for k, v in dct.items():
    add_dict_keys(v, arr)

print(dct)  # has updated values
```